# HTTP 500 between Rails gem yt and youtube API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, youtube-api

I'm having a problem with the yt gem on rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.3.0

Basically i'm using an observer to store data from a youtube link using the yt gem. However when the gem tries to get data from youtube, i get a HTTP 500 error and this :

```
A request to YouTube API returned no items but some were expected: {} You can retry the same request manually by running: curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=&key=AIzaSyCdfdv_akpDhDZEOfrrSkws4P2WMXEKDAU&part=snippet"
```

Here is the console trace aswell :

```
Started POST "/videos" for ::1 at 2017-05-04 17:05:52 +0200
Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+rymp2zyt3eTcZQpGzenHOEnrZelzBpKGXegoLwXDDyIi6oBlyw1iSBhBzH1u5JhGBuAvWx05an61CJg8eaawQ==", "video"=>{"link"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkyV_Ip5vzA"}, "commit"=>"Create Video"}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.5ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 157ms

Yt::Errors::NoItems (A request to YouTube API returned no items but some were expected:
{}

You can retry the same request manually by running:
curl -X GET -H "content-length: 0" -H "user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)" -H "host: www.googleapis.com" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=&key=AIzaSyCdfdv_akpDhDZEOfrrSkws4P2WMXEKDAU&part=snippet"


):
  app/models/video_observer.rb:5:in `before_save'
  app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:12:in `create'


  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (549.9ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (503.4ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (1163.2ms)
```

I tried pretty much everything i found on the internet, nothing worked. Some posts said that there is a problem with ruby and SSL but i don't know anything about it.

Do you have any idea on what could be causing this ?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error before.

While YouTube was processing the video, I tried to call some method and got:
`Yt::Errors::NoItems (A request to YouTube API returned no items but some were expected: {}`

If you need validate the successful upload, please try with:

```
if video.failed?  ~> if video.id.present?
```